# Go to Homescreen on Homebutton press inside my launcher-app

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

Im coding an app that should replace the oem launcher on my Android-HeadUnit.

Now I want to detect inside my App if the Home-Button is pressed, in order to go to the homescreen of my launcher. This should only happen if the launcher is already in the foreground.

For instance, when I'm browsing in the app-drawer, and I press the home button instead of the back-button, it should still get me to the homescreen.

I've already tried some things with Key-Detection, but it seems that this method is depreciated since lolipop. 
My app should run on Api 23 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Foreground app is unable detect and intercept Home button click. Because this is the only guaranteed way for user to close this app and return to home screen. Same for recent apps button

When you press Home button intent with category `android.intent.category.HOME` is sended to system. That way you know what activity will receive that intent, because this launcher is yours app. I've never developed launcher app but I suppose you may catch this intent is onNewIntent if your activity launchMode != standard

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out

Comment: I tried this in my Activitys:
`code`
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        System.out.println(intent.getAction()+"\n"+intent.getFlags());
    }
`code`
It doesn't even get triggered tough...

Comment: @RaspberryDrifter what launchMode attr in your manifest for this activity?

Comment: To be honest, I just found out about launchmodes.
I've tried all 4 modes now and none of them seems to make a difference on tis matter.